# How to modify this code so that changes in the dropdown of the child page are only reflected in the parent after apply & not on onchange? - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my Code for `Parent`. As you can see the child is only opened when `this.state.isFilterPageOpen` is `true`. Basically I have a filter `button` in my parent page, clicking on which the `this.state.isFilterPageOpen` variable is set `true` and filter overlay page opens.

```
{this.state.isFilterPageOpen &&
<FilterPage
            data={this.state.dataDefault}
            applyFilter={this.applyFilter}
            applyDefault={this.applyDefault}
            filtered={this.state.filteredChild}
            onceSubmitted={this.state.filterOnceSubmitted}
            closeFilterChildPage={this.closeFilterChildPage}
          />}
```

This is my relevant pieces of code from the `Filter Page` (which is displayed as a popup/overlay over the parent page). I also used `Lodash` here. I have multiple `Select` dropdowns. I am showing just two of them.

```
class FilterPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: this.props.data,
      filtered: this.props.filtered,
      filteredPush: this.props.filtered,
      onceSubmitted: this.props.onceSubmitted,
    };
  }



render() {

    // lines of code //

const indexSource = _.findIndex(filteredPush, (o) => { return o.id === 'Source'; });
const indexDestination = _.findIndex(filteredPush, (o) => { return o.id === 'Destination'; });


return (

// lines of code

<div className='closefilterview-div'>
              <input
                type='image'
                className='closefilterpage'
                src={close}
                alt="close"
                onClick={() => {
                this.props.closeFilterChildPage();
}}
          />
     </div>

<ButtonComponent
              text='Apply Filter'
              className='button filter-apply'
              width='100'
              display='inline-block'
              onClick={() => {
                this.setState({
                  onceSubmitted: true,
                  filtered: this.state.filteredPush
                }, () => {
                  this.props.applyFilter(this.state.filtered);
                });
                }}
            />// button for apply

            // other lines of code

            <div className='dropdown'>Source
              <Select
                placeholder='ALL'
                onChange={(entry) => {
                  let valuesSource = [];
                  for (let i = 0; i < entry.length; i = i + 1) {
                    valuesSource.push(entry[i].value);
                  }
                  if(indexSource === -1) {
                    filteredPush.push({ id: 'Source', value: valuesSource });
                  } else {
                    filteredPush[indexSource].value = valuesSource;
                  }
                  this.setState({ filteredPush }); // setstate here causing the issue
                }}
                value={(indexSource === -1) ? [] : filteredPush[indexSource].value}
                multi={true}
                options={this.getOptions('Source')}
              />
             </div>
             <div className='dropdown'>Destination
              <Select
                placeholder='ALL'
                onChange={(entry) => {
                let valuesDest = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < entry.length; i = i + 1) {
                  valuesDest.push(entry[i].value);
                }
                if(indexDestination === -1) {
                  filteredPush.push({ id: 'Destination', value: valuesDest });
                } else {
                  filteredPush[indexDestination].value = valuesDest;
                }
                this.setState({ filteredPush }); // setstate here causing the issue
              }}
                value={(indexDestination === -1) ? [] : filteredPush[indexDestination].value}
                multi={true}
                options={this.getOptions('Destination')}
              />
            </div>

            );// end of return
            // lines of code 


}
```

Now the issue is the `filteredPush` and filtered state variable is getting updated on parent page whenever I changes any multi select dropdowns. I have a huge issue when I press on the close button of the page.

Now suppose I select 2 items from destination dropdown and click apply button. Then everything is fine.

Next time I open the filter page again. All the previous selected dropdowns are shown in the placeholders of the respective dropdowns.

Now the issue is when I select any destination (now 3 destination together) but instead of clicking apply button I click the close button to close the filter overlay filter. Then also my state variables `filteredPush` and also filtered is getting updated in the parent as they both get data from the `props`. I have to code in such a way such that `filteredPush` and also filtered are updated on applying and not on `onchange` of respective dropdowns.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You have to clone the object. hoping those are arrays, do this in your constructor. 'filtered: {...this.props.filtered},,' Do the same for other required states too..

Comment: @Panther Can you kindly show me? I am a beginner in React. So I can't understand what you are trying to mean

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mutate the object passed from the parent component like this `filteredPush.push({... })`. Instead, clone the object use _.clone(obj) or _.cloneDeep() if the `filteredPush` is nested, to a new obj then it will not be affected on the parent component. The change in onChange function:

```js
<Select
  placeholder='ALL'
  onChange={(entry) => {
    let valuesSource = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < entry.length; i = i + 1) {
      valuesSource.push(entry[i].value);
    }
    let newFilteredPush = _.cloneDeep(filteredPush)
    if(indexSource === -1) {
      newFilteredPush.push({ id: 'Source', value: valuesSource });
    } else {
      newFilteredPush[indexSource].value = valuesSource;
    }
    this.setState({ filteredPush: newFilteredPush }); 
  }}
  ...
/>
```

Comment: your way is good. But how should I show in the value attribute of the React Select

Answer (score 0):

Firstly welcome to StackOverflow.

To answer your question I believe the problem lies in `<Select onChange={...} />` component. In your code I see you editing the state onChange. Instead, you should only be pushing values to a global(this) variable in the `onChange={fn}`. And setState only on the ButtonCompenents' `onClick={fn}`.

So firstly initialize the `newFilteredPush` in class as an empty array. And then the modified Select would look like -

```
<Select
  placeholder='ALL'
  onChange={(entry) => {
    let valuesSource = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < entry.length; i = i + 1) {
      valuesSource.push(entry[i].value);
    }
    let newFilteredPush = _.cloneDeep(filteredPush)
    if(indexSource === -1) {
      this.newFilteredPush.push({ id: 'Source', value: valuesSource });
    } else {
      this.newFilteredPush[indexSource].value = valuesSource;
    }
  }}
  ...
/>
```

And your ButtonComponent should look like

```
<ButtonComponent
 text='Apply Filter'
 className='button filter-apply'
 width='100'
 display='inline-block'
 onClick={() => {
  this.setState({
  onceSubmitted: true,
  filtered: this.newFilteredPush
 }, () => {
  this.props.applyFilter(this.state.filtered);
 });
}}
/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: your way is good. But how should I show in the value attribute of the React Select

Comment: @Scooby - it should work with `value={(indexDestination === -1) ? [] : this.filteredPush[indexDestination].value}`